# How to change keyboard output in linux mint and ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a problem on my keyboard, The key of "=" on my keyboard is physically broken, each time I want to write "=" I will have to copy it from somewhere else which is a big problem.
I was thinking of a solution, what if I can make something like when I press on the key "b" as an example, the output will be "=".
I'm running Linux Mint, but I was also having this problem when I was using ubuntu.
How I can implement this?

Comment: the better option is to use `xbindkeys` and choose a key combination that produces `=` see manual page for `xbindkeys` from the webpage first.. If you are Ok then install that package..

Comment: That is also simple with `xmodmap`. You may want to search for it, maybe start in this [Arch Linux article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap).